# restriction on group by column

Tags: mysql, group-by, query-optimization

I have the following tables and query in MySQL:

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `events` (
  `pv_name` varchar(60) COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
  `time_stamp` bigint(20) unsigned NOT NULL,
  `event_type` varchar(40) COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
  `data` json,
  PRIMARY KEY (`pv_name`,`time_stamp`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8mb4 COLLATE=utf8mb4_unicode_ci ROW_FORMAT=COMPRESSED;

CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE matching_pv_names (
pv_name varchar(60) NOT NULL,
PRIMARY KEY (pv_name)
) ENGINE=Memory;

SELECT events.pv_name, MAX(events.time_stamp) AS time_stamp
FROM events
WHERE events.time_stamp <= @time_stamp_in
GROUP BY events.pv_name;
```

The query as it stands runs efficiently with 'Using index for group-by'. Is it possible to modify it to restrict the set of pv_names it groups on to those in the `matching_pv_names` table and still keep the 'Using index for group-by' optimization? For example, the following query no longer uses this optimization:

```
SELECT events.pv_name, MAX(events.time_stamp) AS time_stamp
FROM events
WHERE events.time_stamp <= @time_stamp_in
AND events.pv_name IN (SELECT matching_pv_names.pv_name FROM matching_pv_names)
GROUP BY events.pv_name;
```

Is there another way to write it so that it does?

Answer (score 1):

Your first SQL can benefit from `GROUP BY` optimization because it uses one table only and the column that you use for `GROUP BY`  has index on it and the only aggregate function you use is `MAX()`. and you use constant in your WHERE clause.

Once you add another table in the query then [GROUP BY optimization](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/group-by-optimization.html) cannot be applied.

Comment: I think you are right. I was hoping there might be a work around, because I can add a `WHERE events.pv_name LIKE` to the query and retain the optimization.

Comment: You should not strive for getting a specific optimization, but rather strive for the 'best' optimization.

Comment: I believe this is the best optimization, both by the documentation and in testing on my data set.

Answer (score 0):

You have asked about a specific optimization, but isn't the *real* question about efficiency?

See how well this works:

```
SELECT  e.pv_name, MAX(e.time_stamp) AS time_stamp
    FROM  events AS e
    JOIN  matching_pv_names AS m USING(pv_name)
    WHERE  e.time_stamp <= @time_stamp_in
    GROUP BY  e.pv_name;
```

One way to compare the efficiency of two queries, even when the tables are small, is

```
FLUSH STATUS;
SELECT ...;
SHOW SESSION STATUS LIKE 'Handler%';
```

Historically, this construct has optimized poorly:  `IN ( SELECT ... )`.  (I don't know whether it is working poorly for your query in your version.)